# How to modify CommandBandLayout reg key value

Tags: internet-explorer, add-in

How can I modify [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\CommandBar] CommandBandLayout value to make sure my addon is first in the command bar?

any help here appreciated
Thanks,
Manoj

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

Mucking with internal data structures can corrupt IE state and subsequently get your product blocked as malware.

Answer (score -1):

this can simply be done by making a .reg file. This file can be used to modify the registry

It should go like this:

Regedit version

Registry path
Dataname:datatype:datavalue

Just put this into an installer or whatever you are using
Ps. It is hard to type on an iPod touch

Please refer to support.microsoft.com/kb/310516